# Appium Tests with Crosswalk application

Tags: android, cordova, appium, crosswalk-runtime

I'd like to run Appium tests on a Crosswalk-Cordova application, and I wonder if anyone knows if that is even a possibility right now. My doubts stem from not being able to switch to WebView with that setup.

Has anyone able to get it to work? Any Appium-Croswalk-Cordova specialists out there?

Comment: There is a workaround now. https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4597

Answer (score 1):

Crosswalk don't support Appium test right now. It's only support selenium+crosswalk-web-driver. You can refer to link get more [Crosswalk Webdriver](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-WebDriver) detail.